# Nested loop or method?

Tags: java, loops, methods, nested

Hi guys sorry if I duplicate but I can't find answer. I'm a beginner and looking for better solution/optimize if its any.
I need to search solution for my equation. I got `table[n]` and `T1[n]`.

`table[n]` got 5 field loop1, loop2, loop3, Max, Min

`T1[table.length]` is only to keep Solution

Equation must be :

```
table[0].loop1*T1[0]+table[1].loop1*T1[1]+...+table[n].loop1*T1[n]=x
table[0].loop2*T1[0]+table[1].loop2*T1[1]+...+table[n].loop2*T1[n]=y
table[0].loop3*T1[0]+table[1].loop3*T1[1]+...+table[n].loop3*T1[n]=z
```

Problem is I got everything "static" that's mean I nested loop for 6 element of table atm. Here's my code.

```
out : 
 for ( T1[0]=table[0].Min ; T1[0] <= T1[0].Max; T1[0]+=1) {
    for ( T1[1]=table[0].Min ; T1[1] <= T1[0].Max; T1[1]+=1) {
       for ( T1[2]=table[0].Min ; T1[2] <= T1[0].Max; T1[2]+=1) {
          for ( T1[3]=table[0].Min ; T1[3] <= T1[0].Max; T1[3]+=1) {
             for ( T1[4]=table[0].Min ; T1[3] <= T1[0].Max; T1[4]+=1) {
                for ( T1[5]=table[0].Min ; T1[4] <= T1[0].Max; T1[5]+=1) {
   if (T1[0]*table[0].loop1+...+T1[4]*table[5].loop1=x &&
       T1[0]*table[0].loop2+...+T1[4]*table[5].loop2=y &&
       T1[0]*table[0].loop3+...+T1[4]*table[5].loop3=z   ){
t1.setSolution;
System.out.println("u got it"); break out;
}}}}}}}
```

Problems:

1. Don't know how (proper word) dynamically? nested loop for table.length. Means i give him table[n] element and he nested n loop... If its make no sense example. table[n]

   `for(t[0]... ){
      for(t[1]... ){
       for(t[2]... ){
        for(t[n]... ){ // do what u have to }}}}`
2. Any way to optimize code ?
   Thanks in advance!

Comment: The word you are looking for is recursion, this will allow dynamic levels of nesting.

Comment: Rewrite your program in a recursive function, that's what you need

Comment: }}}}}}} <-- that suggests a better solution is present by suggeststing a better solution is present.

Comment: Also you don't need to iterate over the last values i.e. T1[5] can be calculated. (Actually with three equations the last three values can be calculated)

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion but a faster way to solve this sort of linear equation is to solve it once you have enough knowns.

You have 5 variables which are multiplied by 5 constants and three equations.  This will be you lots of a degrees of freedom, however once you explore the combinations of the first two variables the remaining variables become solvable as a linear equation i.e. as a matrix equation.

```
[ T1[2]      [ x - T1[0]*table[0].loop1 - T1[1]*table[1].loop1
  T1[3]   =    y - T1[0]*table[0].loop2 - T1[1]*table[1].loop2   * A^-1
  t1[4] ]      z - T1[0]*table[0].loop3 - T1[1]*table[1].loop3 ]
```

Where A^-1 is the inverse of the matrix of coefficients for T1[2..4]

This will reduce an O(N^5) problem space to O(N^2) problem space.

Comment: In most cases,  any solution that is O (N^2) can be reduced by using recursion.  Or at the least made into O (N). Could this be done from your example?

Comment: @EvanBechtol if a solution can be reduce to O(N) it is an O(N) solution.  An O(N^2) solution cannot be reduced.  Do you mean that with recursion, you can have one loop which re-curses to a method with a second loop?

Comment: No, I mean that if you have an algorithm that results with a time complexity of O (N^2) it is extremely likely that through recursion the complexity can be reduced to O (N).

Comment: This contains a better explanation of what I am asking: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2057/when-can-i-use-dynamic-programming-to-reduce-the-time-complexity-of-my-recursive

Comment: @EvanBechtol Using recursion can lead to a more natural problem description, however it has nothing to do with performance.  There are ways to improve the performance of dynamic programming, but these techniques work even if you are not using dynamic programming.